Why didn't Paul challenge Stilgar for leadership as Stilgar asked?
Harkonnen forces attack Sietch Tabr, resulting in Stilgar's injury, and he
requests that Paul take command of the Fremen warriors:

Stilgar: Usul, in the South...only leaders are allowed to speak.
You must take my place.
Paul: I can't do that.
Stilgar: It is a good time to cross blades with me.

Then, Paul is depicted as leading the Fremen warriors, ignoring Stilgar's
earlier request to cross blades and establish leadership.
Why didn't Paul challenge Stilgar for leadership as Stilgar asked?

Stilgar was one of Paul's staunchest supporters and best fighters. Paul did not want to give that up.

Is this some kind of experiment to extrapolate the entire plot just from answers on this site? You've questioned half the movie at this point

@IG_42 movies based on novels are notorious for omitting background information and exposition that explains important plot points.  Movies have only a couple of hours to tell the story and this often forces them to edit out many details.  For example, the last scenes of the film 2001: A Space Odyssey are incomprehensible, but reading the book explains them.  I suspect Hao Lano has only seen the recent Dune films and they don't have enough detail to explain these smaller plot points.

Reading the book might be a good solution then? Or there are several precis of the novels online, e.g. on SparkNotes.

Paul literally answers this question seconds after the fight is suggested.

@SottoVoce if you look at this user's history, it's clear he wants to offload the burden of thinking into this website. He did the same with Spiderverse. It has nothing to do with not understanding a film adaptation, since he'll ask questions about things literally answered 5 seconds after the scene. He's stream-of-consciousness asking everything he sees.

Paul is the rightful Duke of Arrakis and intends to take control of the planet back from the Harkonnens.  He must govern the planet - which includes all the Fremen sietches - and this means Paul cannot also manage the daily life of Sietch Tabr.  Paul needs to preserve Stilgar's leadership over the sietch so Paul can govern Arrakis.
The book deals with this in Chapter 43.  A partial quote of Paul's conversation with Stilgar is:

"When I am duke in Arrakeen with Chani by my side, do you think I'll have time to concern myself with every detail of governing Tabr sietch?" Paul asked.  "Do you concern yourself with the internal problems of every family?" Stilgar continued staring at the knife. "Do you think I wish to cut off my right arm?" Paul demanded.  Slowly Stilgar looked up at him.
"You!" Paul said. "Do you think I wish to deprive myself or the tribe of your wisdom and strength?"


In addition, Paul didn't want to be pushed around by the expectations of the Fremen (who had created the expectation that Paul would challenge and kill Stilgar)

@Andrew: My remembrance is fuzzy, but wasn't he still fighting against the idea that he would unleash the Jihad, and trying to use the Fremens, yet stay distant from them in an effort to avoid that outcome?

Yes, I think that's right
